# Animate headerTintColor

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

i'm following this tutorial:
https://medium.com/appandflow/react-native-scrollview-animated-header-10a18cb9469e

For animate the react-navigation header background color on scroll.
It works.

I want also animate the headerTintcolor, it must be white for the firsts 200px and gray for the others.
But i can't because if i try to use:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation, screenProps }) =>  { 
....
headerTintColor: (navigation.state.params.animatedColorValue  ? navigation.state.params.animatedColorValue : '#fff')
...
```

i receive an error.

how can i change it after 200px of scroll?
thanks!